# CSV error opening file

Tags: csv, python-3.6

I am getting an error opening a file that I can't resolve.  I am able to open
this exact file with no issues using another small program I wrote.

First Program (**doesn't work**):

```
import csv


passwd = "f:\mark\python\etc_password.txt"
output = "f:\mark\python\output.txt"

with open(passwd, 'r') as passwd1, open(output, 'w') as output1:
    ro = csv.reader(passwd1, delimiter=':')
    wo = csv.writer(output1, delimiter='\t')

for record in ro:
    # if not record[0].startswith('#'):
    if len(record) > 1:
        wo.writerow((record[0], record[2]))
```

---

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    for record in ro:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

---

Second Program (**works**):

```
etcfile = "f:\mark\python\etc_password.txt"
users = {}
with open(etcfile, "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            info = line.split(':')
            users[info[0]] = info[2]

for username in sorted(users):
    print("{}:{}".format(username, users[username]))
```

The first program has the issue that I can't figure out.  The second program works just fine opening the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` is telling you
you cannot read from a closed file. If you look at the indentation of your
first program, you are opening a csv reader to a file which is then closed
at the end of the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) block. A simpler example of this behavior would be

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: file = open('test.csv')

In [3]: ro = csv.reader(file)

In [4]: file.close()

In [5]: for record in ro:
   ...:     print(record)
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1f7adaf76d31> in <module>()
----> 1 for record in ro:
      2     print(record)
      3 

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```